# Getting "Error: Vuetify is not properly initialized" even after initializing in ES6+ in browser

Tags: vuetify.js

I am in Browser trying to initialize Vuetify and I believe this used to work but now fails...

```
//In Node
app.use(serve("./node_modules/vuetify/dist"));

// On Client
<script type="module">
    import * as Vuetify from '/vuetify/vuetify.js';
    const global = window || global;
    global.Vuetify = Vuetify;
    Vue.use(Vuetify, {
        ...
    });
</script>
```

When I run I get

```
Error in beforeCreate hook: "Error: Vuetify is not properly initialized, see https://vuetifyjs.com/getting-started/quick-start#bootstrapping-the-vuetify-object"
```

I tried changing to...

```
//In Node
app.use(serve("./node_modules/vuetify"));

// On Client
<script type="module">
    import Vuetify from "/vuetify/lib";
    const global = window || global;
    global.Vuetify = Vuetify;
    Vue.use(Vuetify, {
        ...
    });
</script>
```

But it still fails this time with

```
GET https://localhost:3001/vuetify/lib net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

I even tried changing to...

```
//In Node
app.use(serve("./node_modules/vuetify"));

// On Client
<script type="module">
    import Vuetify from "/vuetify/lib/index.js";
    const global = window || global;
    global.Vuetify = Vuetify;
    Vue.use(Vuetify, {
        ...
    });
</script>
```

Then I get...

```
GET https://localhost:3001/vuetify/lib/components net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

I think the js files are not proper ES6 definitions (IE no extensions mjs, cjs) but is there a way to get it to work?

For additional context this is how I load Vue

```
import Vue from '/vue/vue.esm.browser.js'
const global = window || global;
global.Vue = Vue;
```

This works fine

Answer (score 0):

you could try importing the script in a script tag: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/vuetify

I think the link you want is this: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/2.0.17/vuetify.js